# Как выполнить некоторые действия с QLineEdit (их два) по нажатию разных кнопок

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, qpushbutton, qlineedit

Из `QLineEdit`(их два) считать символы, выбираю нужную строку `QListWidget`:

1. Добавить строку, состоящую из `QLineEdit` (их 2-а);
2. Изменить строку на `QLineEdit`

Кнопка **`"New"`** должна добавить значения (из двух `QLineEdit`) в список, после выбранной строки, а кнопка **`"Mod"`**, изменить выбранную строку на новую. Вроде все разъяснил.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QPushButton,
                             QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout, QApplication, QListWidget, QLineEdit, QListWidgetItem,
                             QFileDialog)


class Example(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        Bt_1 = QPushButton("New", self)
        Bt_1.move(10,10)

        Bt_2 = QPushButton("Mod", self)
        Bt_2.move(10,35)

        List = QListWidget(self)
        List.move(90,10)

        Line = QLineEdit(self)
        Line. move(10, 60)
        Line.resize(70, 20)

        Line_2 = QLineEdit(self)
        Line_2.move(10, 85)
        Line_2.resize(70, 20)

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 400, 400)
        self.show()

        def on_addClicked():
               text = self.Line + " " + Line_2.text()
               if len(text):
                    lvi = QListWidgetItem(self.List)[0]
                    lvi.setText(0, text)

        def delete():
            pass    

        Bt_1.clicked.connect(on_addClicked)
        Bt_2.clicked.connect(delete)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: 1-ая кнопка должна добавить значения(из QLineEdit) в список,после выбранной строки,а 2-ая изменить выбранную строку на новую(из QLineEdit). p.s. создает строку из двух значений. Вроде все разъяснил.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я вас правильно понял, то это может выглядеть так:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QPushButton, QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout, 
                             QApplication, QListWidget, QLineEdit, QListWidgetItem,
                             QFileDialog)

class Example(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        bt_1 = QPushButton("New", self)
        bt_1.move(10,10)
        bt_2 = QPushButton("Mod", self)
        bt_2.move(10,35)
        bt_1.clicked.connect(self.addElement)
        bt_2.clicked.connect(self.editElement)        

        self.listWidget = QListWidget(self)
        self.listWidget.move(90,10)

        self.lineEdit = QLineEdit(self)
        self.lineEdit. move(10, 60)
        self.lineEdit.resize(70, 20)

        self.lineEdit_2 = QLineEdit(self)
        self.lineEdit_2.move(10, 85)
        self.lineEdit_2.resize(70, 20)

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 400, 400)

    def addElement(self):
        text = (self.lineEdit.text() + " " + self.lineEdit_2.text()).strip()
        if text:
            self.listWidget.addItem(text)
        self.lineEdit.setText("")
        self.lineEdit_2.setText("")

# lvi ???       
#            lvi = QListWidgetItem(self.listWidget)[0]
#            lvi.setText(0, text)


    def editElement(self):
        """ Pедактируем выбранный элемент списка QListWidget """

        itemNumber = self.listWidget.currentRow()
        item       = self.listWidget.item(itemNumber)
        if item is not None:
            text = "{} {}".format(self.lineEdit.text(), self.lineEdit_2.text()).strip()
            if text:
                item.setText(text)
        self.lineEdit.setText("")
        self.lineEdit_2.setText("")


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]